# shibboleth single sign on in java application server

Tags: java, spring, single-sign-on, shibboleth

I have tried reading the shibboleth wiki but was not able to understand how to integrate shibboleth single sign on in our spring based multiple web-apps.
We need a database based authentication , so we should use jaas ?
How would it work ? Can someone please detail the steps like something as follows 
a) Install shibboleth idp
b) configure jaas as the service provider etc ?

Any help would be appreciated to point in the right direction

Thanks

Comment: Are you only interested in setting up the IdP?  The SP does not care at all how you set up the IdP. That is, your SPs (web applications) don't need to know that the IdP is using JAAS, and the SPs do not need any type of JAAS integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well Shibboleth architecture is not something you can understand easily and Shibboleth wiki is well... massive. Fortunately there are many good sources of knowledge, you just need to know where to begin.

from Shibboleth wiki the most important is [FlowsAndConfig](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/FlowsAndConfig) page and of course whole [Understanding Shibboleth](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/UnderstandingShibboleth) category

Guys from SWITH made some nice [schematics](http://www.switch.ch/aai/support/tools/wayf.html) and [tutorials](http://www.switch.ch/aai/support/howto/) on their sites, I found their materials well organised.

*Edit: this are really good instructions to understand whole concept **[easy](http://www.switch.ch/aai/demo/2/simple.html) [medium](http://www.switch.ch/aai/demo/2/medium.html) [expert](http://www.switch.ch/aai/demo/2/expert.html)** I couldn't find it before on SWITCH sites so I post it now.*

There are also [Guanxi](http://codebrane.com/brane/) (Java implementation of Shibboleth concepts) presentations with nice schematics

And finally extended [shibboleth architecture with some custom modules](http://translate.google.pl/translate?hl=pl&sl=pl&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.man.poznan.pl%2Ftrac%2Fsp-gas-client%2Fwiki%2FSpMain)(unfortunately not in english so I linked translated version)

For Shibboleth IdP installation please refer to [wiki](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPInstall) it is really easy to do